# How make other machines join my private ethereum network.

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I have created a private ethereum network in my machine, and now I want that other machines join my network.

I think I have to send them the IP of the bootnode, but the question is : what about the genesis block ? ..

to init a node we run `"geth --datadir node1/ init genesis.json"` so do they need my genesis file ?

Answer (score 1):

The `genesis` block is just there to start the blockchain, you don't need it to be manually transported to everyone to be able to connect.
from the official `geth` [manual](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network#starting-up-your-member-nodes) :

> Starting Up Your Member Nodes
>
> With the bootnode operational and externally reachable (you can try telnet   to ensure it's indeed reachable), start every subsequent Geth node pointed to the bootnode for peer discovery via the --bootnodes flag. It will probably also be desirable to keep the data directory of your private network separated, so do also specify a custom --datadir flag.
>
> `geth --datadir path/to/custom/data/folder --networkid 15 --bootnodes <bootnode-enode-url-from-above>`

So just connecting to the boot node will spark the synchronization, which is related to the folder you specify in `--datadir`.

Comment: it works just when I copy the some genesis.json and I do "init".. I can't realize why I need the genesis block to be part of an existing network.